# If $M, N$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with same dimension, then if $M$ is subset of $N$, then $M=N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, self-learning

If $M, N$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with same dimension, then if $M$ is subset of $N$, then $M=N$.

I think i need to show that both vector spaces are spanned by the same bases in order to do this or to prove $N$ is subset of $M$?

But i am not sure how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me reformulate the problem:

> If $M$ is a (finite dimensional) subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $N$ and $\dim M=\dim N$, then $M=N$.

The clause that $M$ is finite dimensional is redundant, but it's not important, as you have it in your assignment.

Suppose $M\ne N$ and let $v\in N$, $v\notin M$. If $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $M$, then $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v\}$ is a linearly independent set in $N$: this is impossible, because a linearly independent sets in $N$ has at most $n=\dim N=\dim M$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\;B:=\{m_1,...,m_k\}\;$ be a basis of $\;M\;$ . Then $\;B\;$ is a linearly independent set of $\;N\;$ as $\;M\le N\;$ . But we're also given $\;k=\dim M=\dim N\;$ , so...complete here.

Comment: .Are we to assume here that since M is sub of N ,So bases of M can be extended to form basis of N ,But that would mean that bases of M has more tan k elements ,which is contradiction .

Comment: No. If the extension is non-trivial (i.e.;, if you **really** do add at least one single vector to a basis of $\;M\;$), that'd mean $\;\dim N\ge k+1>\dim M\;$, contradicting the given data.

Comment: Then how should i go about proof

Comment: Just as you said! Or directly by definition of dimension: since $\;\dim M=k\;$ **and also** $\;\dim N=k\;$ , and since $\;M\le N\;$ , basis $\;B\;$ **must** be *also* a basis of $\;N\;$ , and thus any element in $\;N\;$ is a lin. comb. of $\;B\;$, which is an element of $\;M\;$ .

Comment: There's no reason to formulate it as a proof by contradiction. We have a set of linearly independent vectors of the right size to be a basis.

Comment: @Henrik That's true...but there's also no reason to back off from a proof by contradiction. Whatever makes it easier for the OP, and later, when it is thoroughly understood, he can choose what way to prove it.

Comment: @Timbuc where i am wrong in my first comment

Comment: @K.Dutta In saying that extending a basis of $\;M\;$ would mean...etc.,  if you mean that *I meant this*, then that's wrong: I meant what I wrote below that comment.

Comment: @Timbuc My idea was that since M is a subset of N  (also assuming m elements in basis of M ) ,since N is larger than M ,say if we say that we require to extend basis of M to cover all elements of N ,But thats not so because their dimensions would then not be same .

Answer (score 1):

I think the notation etc can get over-engineered and technical. Here is an attempt to look at things more straightforwardly.

Here are two facts you should know about vector spaces:

Every basis of a finite dimensional vector space has the same number of elements.

Any linearly independent subset of a vector space can be extended to a basis.

You know that $M$ is contained in $N$, and they have the same dimension $r$. A basis $B$ of $M$ therefore has $r$ elements, and as a basis is a linearly independent subset of $M$ and hence of $N$ (because $N$ contains $M$).

$B$, as a basis of $M$, can therefore be extended to a basis of $N$, which will have $r$ elements - so $B$ is already a basis of $N$ as well as of $M$.

Since $B$ is a basis of $N$, any element $v\in N$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors. But this is just an expression of $v$ as an element of $M$. So every element of $N$ is also an element of $M$ and the two are equal.